# How to use ScrollView inside Bottomsheet?

Tags: android, scrollview, bottom-sheet

I have integrated NestedScrollView inside BottomSheetDialogFragment layout. But scrolling is not happening if bottomsheet is in fully expanded state.

Tried with overScrollMode with all options and its not working.

Attached codes I have tried. Removed constraints and margins due o confidentiality.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/scollContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <include
                        layout="@layout/abc"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         />

                    <include
                        layout="@layout/xyz"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Here is a lib that works with nestedscrollview https://github.com/skimarxall/AnchorSheetBehavior and the related blog post https://medium.com/@marxallski/from-bottomsheetbehavior-to-anchorsheetbehavior-262ad7997286 in case you want to read up on the same.

Comment: @Raghunadan I cant use a library for this project. And forgot to update that its a BottomSheetDialogFragment.